# How to use Method interceptor in Spring 3.0?

Tags: java, interceptor, spring-3

Which interceptor can use in Spring 3.0 ?
I want to get Action name and method name in this.

HandlerInterceptorAdapter is working , but i cant get the method name and action name on this..

Any Help..?

### dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<!-- Handle Interceptor -->
<mvc:interceptors> <bean   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" 
    /> <mvc:interceptor> <mvc:mapping path="/*" /> 
<bean class="com.asd.MyInterceptor" 
    /> 
</mvc:interceptor> </mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement HandlerInterceptor interface. One of the parameters in preHandle and postHandle methods of that interface is Object handler. It is in fact a HandlerMethod instance which should provided you everything you need.